# Order by datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a table that contains a datetime field type, and I want to sort the select syntax depends on it descending, just like the following:

> 2012-12-12 01:44:20
>
> 2012-12-11 01:44:40
>
> 2012-12-10 01:40:36
>
> 2012-12-09 12:28:19
>
> 2012-12-09 12:19:21
>
> 2012-12-09 12:11:50
>
> 2012-12-09 12:00:11
>
> 2012-12-09 11:59:26
>
> 2012-12-09 11:57:08
>
> 2012-12-09 11:55:21

Answer (score 36):

```
ORDER BY columnname DESC
```

**Ta-dah!**

Comment: @Samer: It works indeed, but it would work as well if you remove `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. In this case it would change nothing

Comment: I used this syntax and it works correctly: 
order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`my_column_name`) desc

Comment: And as I said `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` pointless here. `ORDER BY my_column_name DESC` is enough

Comment: I added +1 only the Ta-dah!

Comment: Don't know why, but my query only worked with UNIX_TIMESTAMP, and the fieldtype is DATETIME

Comment: @VianickOliveri it makes no sense

Answer (score 22):

```
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(columnname) DESC
```

The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is needed, because mysql tests them as strings (ex `9:00` appears after `16:00`)

Comment: This doesn't make sense, it wouldn't be `9:00`, it would be `09:00` which sorts correctly even if sorted as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CAST(columnname AS DATETIME) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case *dtEvent* field is datetime type.
This is the only solution I found:

```
SELECT myTable.recordId, myTable.dtEvent
FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.dtEvent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CAST(YEAR(myTable.dtEvent) AS UNSIGNED),
    CAST(MONTH(myTable.dtEvent) AS UNSIGNED),
    CAST(DAY(myTable.dtEvent) AS UNSIGNED) 
LIMIT 100;
```